# best coding practices, loops

Tags: c++, standards, microcontroller

I'm writing some code and I have two possible methods of achieving the goal, so I thought I would ask on here and find out what people think, so the first method is

```
valid=0;
count=0;
while(!valid&&count<6) 
{
   valid=read_fix_from_flash(download_fix_starting_position.ul);//returns 1 if successful
   count++
}
```

or the alternative

```
valid=0;
for(count=6;count>0;count--)
{
  valid=read_fix_from_flash(download_fix_starting_position.ul);//returns 1 if successful
  if(valid){
    break;
  }
}
```

In my opinion the second method is the better option but I have seen examples using the first method.

Comment: Your conditions differ (for `count`)

Comment: Both approaches are pretty much the same (if done right), as a `for` loop is a `while` loop in disguise.

Comment: You could use `&&` in the condition in the `for` loop as well, combining the two

Comment: Best coding practices include spaces around the operators and after semicolons.  Also using `&&` (logical AND) and not `&` (bitwise AND).

Comment: I like the `for` loop because you are using bitwise AND operator on a condition in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the `while` variant more, because it expresses that the number of iterations is variable. Additionally, it is better to use the boolean and `&&` instead of the bitwise and `&` here.